# Valid Breakpoint becomes disabled when debugging

Tags: delphi, debugging, breakpoints, delphi-10.4-sydney

At design time, I create a valid `Breakpoint` in my Delphi 10.4.2 VCL Application source by clicking in the gutter:

[image]

But as soon as I run the app in DEBUG MODE by pressing the `F9` key, the BreakPoint becomes disabled:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: This is sometimes (often) a bug and often restarting the IDE helps. But there are also other reasons: Make sure that you are using the project's DEBUG configuration (not RELEASE), that Project Options / Building / Delphi Compiler / Compiling has all Debugging options turned on, and that you have recently built (Shift+F9) the project.

Comment: Before starting the IDE, a previous process (TeraCopy) had used all of my RAM Memory (50 GB) when doing a huge backup. So, after restarting Windows, the problem was solved.

Comment: Do you have 50 GB of RAM? If so, I am very envious of you.

Comment: It's even 64 GB. The 50 GB is the amount I gave to my Windows 10 Parallels VM.

Comment: My 12-year-old Windows 7 computer doesn't support more than 16 GB, but I find that to be rather limiting. My next computer will definitely have 64 GB too.

Comment: My MacBook Pro with 64 GB is only one year old. Before that, I used a Windows 7 machine with 16 GB RAM. When using VMs, a lot of RAM is useful. Although, using Windows in a VM also creates some problems which fortunately I have solved so far.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand First gen i7?  Or even late gen Core2?! I would go insane.  It's time, my friend!

Comment: @J...: i7. I don't like to buy products and only use them for a short period of time; that's not good for the environment or your personal finances. Instead, I spend a lot of money on a *really* high-end system, and then I expect to be able to use it for a long time. And mostly, [my system](https://rejbrand.se/rejbrand/fotografier/green_workstation_t.jpg) still feels powerful and fast.

Comment: Very nicely tidy desk! I want a desk this clean!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, I'm the same way, but a system that old would seriously negatively impact my productivity, and that's not good either.  I feel anything older than around Haswell now is not suitable for heavy professional work.  I usually have about 6-8 IDEs open at any given time, though - if you're only working on one thing at at time I guess I could see an older system still being OK, but if you're feeling that 16GB limit I feel you must be waiting for the CPU a lot too...

Comment: @J...: The CPU is by far not a bottleneck, but the RAM is to some extent. I typically have 10-20 Firefox tabs open, a handful of RAD Studios, a few Microsoft Office applications, GIMP, and the Lightworks video editor open, so I would definitely make sure my next system has plenty of RAM (at least 64 GB).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The CPU is a bottleneck for very short intervals.  Some people care less about micro-lags and those 300ms waits for windows to show, menus to drop, etc, so maybe that's less of an issue for you, but it drives me mad once a system gets past a certain threshold of UI lag.

Comment: @J...: I typically don't experience that kind of lag. Windows and menus open instantly (except for the Aero animations).

Comment: Are you sure the CPU is to blame for these lags? I reckon opening a menu or displaying a window isn't a very CPU-intensive task, and should require very little effort for a modern 3 GHz quad-code eight-thread (HT) CPU. Likely the culprit is disk I/O, not CPU.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I disable all UI animations.  That's probably why you don't notice it - just used to it being slow.  I just upgraded from an i7 4770 to a 10850K and the difference is huge.  I still go back to the old system for certain things that I haven't ported across yet and it is annoyingly sluggish by comparison.  Probably not all CPU - some of it is also bus and memory improvements, but both systems have equally fast SSDs, so the disk I/O is not the major difference.